# Misleading suggestion by go linter

Tags: go

I am trying to write an extremely simple function that just accepts a pointer to `os.File` and returns its number of lines.

Here is my function

```golang
// GetNumberOfLines returns the number of lines of file
func GetNumberOfLines(file *io.Reader) (numberOfLines int, err error) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        numberOfLines++
    }

    return numberOfLines, nil
}
```

I get the following suggestion from the linter

> `file` can be `io.Reader` (interfacer)go-golangci-lint

[image]

However when I follow the linter's advice, I get the following error from the compiler:

> cannot use file (variable of type *io.Reader) as io.Reader value in argument to bufio.NewScanner: missing method ReadcompilerInvalidIfaceAssign

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: It said `io.Reader`, not `*io.Reader`

Comment: [Don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion said to use `io.Reader`, not `*io.Reader`. Interfaces typically contain pointers already, so there's rarely a need to use a pointer to an interface.